# Debugging Python scripting for testing Embedded system connected with Rasbperry pi (RPi)

Tags: python, testing, raspberry-pi, automated-tests, embedded

I am looking to test embedded system product using Python scripting and I need some guidance.

The setup: A Raspberry pi have been connected to the embedded system PCB and I access that Raspberry pi remotely using ssh or vncserver.

The issue: I am using PyCharm on my laptop to access the Python scripts. Since the embedded system is connected to Raspberry pi, I am not able to debug using my laptop as I would not be able to get the values of variables etc while debugging. So I installed PyCharm on RPi but it keeps on crashing frequently which I guess is because RPi is not able to take that much load as it also connected to VNCServer while using PyCharm.

What I am looking for: Some guidance how to debug in such a case so I can test whether scripts have issue or device is faulty or something else. A better and efficient method for debugging in such a scenario where there are multiple layers.

I have limited exposure so I may be missing out something. Please feel free to correct me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need the RP as middle-man in the first place? Are you debugging over the internet or some such?

Comment: Yes.  RPi is in office connected to ethernet and I can access it from any system with VPN or from office's network. I have limited knowledge in this kind of setup where there is external layer of hardware which is to be tested. I was given it like this so I have been using this way only. I am not aware of more efficient way for this.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Just in case someone is looking for the answer to this question, Pycharm paid version allows remote debugging over ssh. That worked for me.